# angle between line joining two gps co-ordinates and the north pole (axis)

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have two gps co-ordinates p1 and p2 as in the figure.

```
      p1
     /
    /\ (theta)
   /--------------> North
  /
 p2
```

I want to calculate the angle (theta) subtended by the line joining two gps co-ordinates on the north axis (pole).

But I have no idea how to proceed.

Any help in this regard would be highly appreciated.

Comment: The value of theta would be different for any point along the line (p1,p2)

Answer (score 0):

use your two points to create a Vector, a
calculate a vector that points north and then plug into equation below and then take the inverse of it to get the angle.

[theta between two vectors](http://www.wikihow.com/Find-the-Angle-Between-Two-Vectors)

Comment: i think what you want is called bearing.  google 'bearing latitude'.